# Using a Docker web container, how do I access localhost from a custom url, even though the ip keeps changing?

Tags: docker, localhost

Using Ubuntu 20.04.

I have a Docker web container that I can access locally at localhost:8000 I want to instead access this by typing hello.localhost in my browser.

I can accomplish this by adding the containers ip address to my /etc/hosts file but the problem is that this ip address can change. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would solve this using port publishing. Let's say you have multiple containers; we'll call them `hello` and `goodbye`. You'd like to access them as `http://hello.localhost` and `http://goodbye.localhost`, without having to append a port number.

You can bind each container to a specific ip on your host, like this:

```
docker run --name hello -p 127.0.0.2:80:8000 myimage
docker run --name goodbye -p 127.0.0.3:80:8000 myimage
```

Here, we've bound port 8000 on container `hello` to `127.0.0.2:80`, and port 8000 on container `goodbye` to `127.0.0.3:80`. All that we need to do now is tell our host about names for these addresses, which we can do by adding something like this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.2  hello.localhost
127.0.0.3  goodbye.localhost
```

Now you can browse to `http://hello.localhost` or `http://goodbye.localhost` (as long as your browser is running on the same machine as your docker containers).